# Making a Web Page Zoom-Proof (Preventing Compression/Expansion of Elements)

Tags: html, css

Is there a simple way to make sure all elements on a page remain in the same exact position regardless of how much one zooms in/zooms out? To clarify, I  don't want the elements compressing as one zooms in and expanding as one zooms out. A good example of what I'd prefer is stack itself! Try zooming in/out. The element's position relative to the original screen size remain totally unchanged - only the user's perspective has changed.

Comment: basically, you want a page that will scroll instead of wrapping: [here](https://css-tricks.com/how-to-create-a-horizontally-scrolling-site/) is a great example on CSSTricks.

Comment: Build a static website instead of a responsive one?

Comment: Ironically, csstricks itself has this problem. Say I've got serious vision problems and have to zoom all the way in just to see anything. It's very difficult to read their navbar when zoomed all the way in.

Answer (score 0):

I have a very simple solution that worked for me. I just put a minimum width attribute to the main element of the HTML page and so now whenever someone zooms in beyond that minimum width value it does not affect the main body as it cannot be any smaller than that.Take a look at these images to see the result

[This is what it looked like before.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0krhi.jpg).

Then I inserted the min-width into the #main which is the id corresponding to the main tag in the html

```css
#main {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: space-around;
  min-width: 1400px;
}
```

And the result is this
 [After adding the CSS code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7NdJ1.png)

As you can see I have zoomed in a lot into the browser and where in the above image there are elements overlapping with each other,now  they stop coming closer after you zoom in a certain amount.
Hope this helps!